# How does the api controller know which method to call without the annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I recently just started using asp.net web api controller.

I call these controller methods via ajax, but by default when I created a web api controller using EF, none of the controller methods had the attributes above them like:

- `[HttpGet]`
- `[HttpPost]`
- `[HttpPut]`
- `[HttpDelete]`

Instead they all have this above them:

`[ResponseType(typeof(ModelName))]`

However, the controller method names did have those annotations in the name of the method like:

- GetModelName()
- PostModelName()
- PutModelName()
- DeleteModelName()

So, when I put the method type in my ajax call to 'Delete' for instance.. is there some kind of name recognition via the method name that has the word 'Delete' in it?  If not, how does the api controller know which method to call without the attributes above them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api):

> To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name

So is basically convention-based.

Answer (score 0):

I need to clarify the answer as Annotation-based method declaring is available!
The most common mistake of "Why `[HttpGet]/[ActionName]/[Route]` doesn't work on ApiController" is the namespace `using System.Web.Http;` vs `using System.Web.Mvc;`. Very tricky!!!

If you found in your ApiController `using System.Web.Mvc;`, then the `[HttpGet]/[ActionName]/[Route]` will be MVC-version, which will NOT be registered in `WebApiConfig.cs`.

So make sure you're using `using System.Web.Http;` in ApiController